# Storing Measurements in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I’m storing body measurements in an app using Core Data. These measurements can either be of type `UnitMass` (i. e. weight) or `UnitLength` (i. e. height). In the app, these measurements are passed using `Measurement` instances which allows for easy converting between metric and imperial units. In Core Data, the measurement’s values are being stored as Doubles using the unit’s `baseUnit()`.

However, I’m unsure of how to store the *unit* in the database. I came up with this:

```
enum BodyMeasurementUnit: Int16 {
    case mass = 0
    case length

    static func unit(for value: Int16) -> BodyMeasurementUnit {
        switch value {
        case 0: return .mass
        default: return .length
        }
    }
}
```

which allows me to store the applicable unit by index. But I’d rather have a function which returns `UnitMass` or `UnitLength` directly. Does anyone of you guys have a better idea? Also, although using an `enum` this way allows me to easily add additional unit types should necessity arise, I feel I’m somehow duplicating Apples’s `Unit*` classes instead of just augmenting them according to my needs. Anyone? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Why do you have to store the unit at all? Isn't that clear from the context? If you store a height/width/... then it is a length. If you store a weight then it is a mass.

Comment: Another way to do it would be to create a CoreData Table called `BodyMeasurementUnit` that had a `name` column and whatever else you need. Add rows for each type of measurement, then, `BodyMeasurement` can have a relation to the corresponding `BodyMeasurementUnit` row.

Comment: @Martin R: It's a table simply storing values. If I store 25, for example, then how would I be able to tell if it is a length or a mass? It’s the unit field which adds the necessary context.

Comment: If you store 25 meter or 100 kg, how do you know *what* is measured?

Comment: There’s a form in the app where you enter the value and select the associated unit.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the unit and the value in two separate variables and then write a computed property returning:

```
enum Return {
    case weight(Int)
    case length(Int)
}
```

, which gives a much simpler API.

The static initializer isn‘t necessary since a rawValue-enum generates its own initializer `init(rawValue: RawValueType)`(`RawValueType=Int here`).

Comment: it would help to see more detail here